# How can I allow dropping a file on the Windows 7 taskbar icon using Java or SWT?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, swt

When I `drag` a file onto the Chrome taskbar icon, Windows asks me `Pin to Google Chrome`.  When  I `shift+drag` a file onto the Chrome taskbar icon, Windows asks me `Open with Google Chrome`.

I would like for my SWT application to have this same behavior, or at least some response to files being dropped onto the taskbar icon.

I have already added a `DropListener` to my root `Shell`, which lets me intercept drop events onto the title bar of my application, but it doesn't respond to drop events on the taskbar icon.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something with the `TaskBar` or `TaskItem`:

```
TaskBar taskBar = Display.getDefault().getSystemTaskBar();

TaskItem taskItem = taskBar.getItem(null);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about these APIs!  Looks like they do a lot of useful stuff, but it doesn't look like I can put a `DropTarget` on either of them.  Definitely pertinent though.